# I want to add background video and put image over it in the banner

Tags: html, css, image, video

I want to add background video and put image over it in the banner. I have already put it but I can't show the image. I want to add background video in first banner and put image over it.
Here is my link: http://veepal.co.in/veepal_design/

I have tried

```html
<div class="pageWrapper">
        <?php include 'header_menu_semi_transperent.php'; ?>
            <div class="pageContent">
                <div id="rev_slider_4_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container" data-alias="concept1">
                    <div id="rev_slider_4_1" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.1.6">
                        <ul>
                            
                            <li data-transition="fade" style=" background: url('assets/images/video-banner.png') no-repeat right top;">

                                <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme tp-videolayer" 
 
     data-frames='[{"delay": 500, "speed": 300, "from": "opacity: 0", "to": "opacity: 1"}, 
                   {"delay": "wait", "speed": 300, "to": "opacity: 0"}]' 
 
     data-type="video" 
     data-videomp4="http://veepal.co.in/veepal_design/assets/video/Mock-up.mp4" 
     data-videowidth="1850" 
     data-videoheight="900" 
     data-autoplay="on" 
     data-nextslideatend="true" 
     data-forcerewind="on" 
     data-videoloop="loopandnoslidestop" 
     data-allowfullscreenvideo="true" 
     
 
     data-x="center" 
     data-y="center" 
     data-hoffset="0" 
     data-voffset="0" 
     data-basealign="slide">
 
</div>

                            </li>    
                            
                            <li data-transition="fade" class="dark" data-slotamount="default" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1500" data-saveperformance="off"><img src="assets/images/sliders/rev/New-banner/1.png" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 1000" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                                <div class="tp-caption tp-shape tp-shapewrapper tp-resizeme" id="slide-897-layer-6" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['0','0','-15','-15']" data-width="['500','400','300','150']" data-height="2" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:2000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:300;s:300;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="2000" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></div>
                                <div class="tp-caption rev-btn " id="slide-12-layer-18" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','top','bottom']" data-voffset="['450','230','300','230']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:0;e:Linear.easeNone;" data-transform_in="y:[50%];opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power3.easeIn;s:300;e:Power3.easeIn;" data-start="3300" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" data-responsive="on" style="z-index: 13; font-size: 20px; line-height: 50px; font-weight: 500; color: #fff;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);padding:0 10px;border-radius:3px;cursor: auto/*margin-top: 130px !important;*/">SEO, SMO, ASO/App Marketing</div><a class="tp-caption main-bg rev-btn " data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','bottom']" data-voffset="['130','110','110','50']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:0;e:Linear.easeNone;" data-style_hover="c:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);bg:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);" data-transform_in="y:[50%];opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power3.easeIn;s:300;e:Power3.easeIn;" data-start="3300" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" data-responsive="off" style="z-index: 13; font-size: 20px; line-height: 50px; font-weight: 500;padding:0 30px;border-radius:3px;" href="search-engine-optimization">BON VOYAGE</a></li>-->
                            <li data-transition="fade" class="dark" data-slotamount="default" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1500" data-saveperformance="off"><img src="assets/images/sliders/rev/New-banner/2.png" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 1000" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                            <li data-transition="fade" class="dark" data-slotamount="default" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1500" data-saveperformance="off"><img src="assets/images/sliders/rev/New-banner/3.png" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 1000" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                            <li data-transition="fade" class="dark" data-slotamount="default" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1500" data-saveperformance="off"><img src="assets/images/sliders/rev/New-banner/4.png" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 1000" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                            <li data-transition="fade" class="dark" data-slotamount="default" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1500" data-saveperformance="off"><img src="assets/images/sliders/rev/slider2/2/04.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 1000" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
                                <h2 class="tp-caption uppercase heavy white tp-resizeme" id="slide-1491-layer-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-50','-50','-50','-50']" data-fontsize="['70','50','35','25']" data-lineheight="['75','75','35','25']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:50px;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:300;s:300;" data-start="1500" data-splitin="chars" data-splitout="none" data-basealign="slide" data-responsive_offset="on" data-responsive="on" data-elementdelay="0.03" style="z-index: 8; white-space: nowrap;">CRM & ERP <span class="main-color">Development</span></h2>
                                <div class="tp-caption tp-shape tp-shapewrapper tp-resizeme" id="slide-897-layer-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['0','0','-15','-15']" data-width="['500','400','300','150']" data-height="2" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:2000;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:300;s:300;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="2000" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></div>
                                <div class="tp-caption rev-btn " id="slide-12-layer-22" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','top','bottom']" data-voffset="['450','230','300','230']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:0;e:Linear.easeNone;" data-transform_in="y:[50%];opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power3.easeIn;s:300;e:Power3.easeIn;" data-start="3300" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" data-responsive="on" style="z-index: 13; font-size: 20px; line-height: 50px; font-weight: 500; color: #fff;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);padding:0 5px;border-radius:3px;cursor: auto/*margin-top: 130px !important;*/">MS Dynamics CRM, Sage CRM, vTiger CRM, Odoo</div><a class="tp-caption main-bg rev-btn " data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','bottom']" data-voffset="['130','110','110','50']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:0;e:Linear.easeNone;" data-style_hover="c:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);bg:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);" data-transform_in="y:[50%];opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:1000;e:Power3.easeIn;s:300;e:Power3.easeIn;" data-start="3300" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" data-responsive="off" style="z-index: 13; font-size: 20px; line-height: 50px; font-weight: 500;padding:0 30px;border-radius:3px;" href="enterprise-solutions">BON VOYAGE</a></li>
                            
                            
                                
                        </ul>
```

Comment: This issue is solved for you?

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<video controls poster="transparent.png"> 
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
```

CSS

```
video { 
   width:305px; 
   height:160px;  
   background:transparent url('poster.jpg') no-repeat 0 0; 
   -webkit-background-size:cover; 
   -moz-background-size:cover; 
   -o-background-size:cover; 
   background-size:cover; 
}
```

For in detail HTML5 Video and Background Images.

http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/03/html5/html5-video-and-background-images/